# C# ClickOnce Application, ProcessModule debug vs. release (missing modules)

Tags: c#, .net, process, module, clickonce

I'm searching for loaded modules in a process which is started by my application.
In debug mode I'm getting a list of 30 loaded modules, that's the full as it should be.

After I release the application, I'm getting only a few of them (ntdll, wow64, wow64win, wow64cpu), all other modules are missing from list, but they are loaded.
Is this some kind of permission issue? How should I fix it, so that I can get the full list of loaded modules in the targeted process? It's a ClickOnce application.

Comment: You are getting the 64-bit view of a 32-bit process.  wow64 is the emulator that a 32-bit process needs to run on a 64-bit operating system.  How you did this is quite hard to guess without any code to look at.  I suppose you'll want to tinker with the EXE project's Platform target setting.  The setting for the Release configuration is wrong.  Change it to match the Debug configuration's setting.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem in debug mode Platform target was x86, and in release Any CPU. Since i'm running x64 i was unable to read modules of 32-bit process as you said. After i changed release settings everything works as it should. Again, thank you.